# Is it inappropriate to ask how long a phone informational and technical interview will take?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I applied for a software dev position two days ago, sent in a couple of requested micro solutions yesterday, and today scheduled an "informational and technical" interview over the phone for next week.

Would it be inappropriate to send another email and ask how long the call should take? Would that send negative impressions, i.e. I don't value their time?

If possible, I'd like to use that time estimate to gauge what I might expect from the interview and how I should study. (That is, will the technical questions be only on theory or will it involve coding?) I did already ask if I would need any special materials for the technical portion, and they said no.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like:

- "For scheduling purposes, how long should I expect the interview to take?"

would be more than appropriate. It's actually a good idea to do for scheduling reasons even ignoring any other benefits (like knowing what to study, etc).

Answer (score 3):

At least in my opinion this is totally fine. And possibly even a good sign. A lot of people attending an interview will be juggling that with their current job and various other commitments.

Asking about a rough estimate of timing makes you seem conciencious and someone who is not just sitting at home all day. All I would say is be careful how you word the question to ensure you do not come across as impatient or uninterested.